# Segmentation. strcmp [C]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I have a file with format: [name][number][amount]
number is taken as a string. and im using it in a strcmp.
Problem is that i get a segmentation fault. I know that on most cases when strcmp signs segmentation fault it means that one of the parameters is null or cant find its "end" ('\0').
I checked with gdb and i cant say if this is the problem.Take a look:

```
> (gdb) bt full
> #0  0x08048729 in lookup (hashtable=0x804b008, hashval=27, 
>     number=0x804b740 "6900101001") 
>         list = 0xffffffff
> #1  0x080487ac in add (hashtable=0x804b008, 
>     number=0x804b740 "9900101001", name=0x804b730 "Smithpolow",
> time=6943) 
>         new_elem = 0xffffffff
>         hashval = 27
> #2  0x08048b25 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff4b4) 
>         number = 0x804b740 "9900101001"
>         name = 0x804b730 "Smithpolow"
>         time = 6943
>         i = 2
```

Code:

```
        typedef struct  HashTable
        {
            int length;
            struct  List *head; 

        } HashTable;

        //(resolving collisions using chaining)
        typedef struct  List
        {
            char *number;
            char *name;
            int time;
            struct List *next;
        } List;

    int primes[]={17,29,51,79,163,331,673,1361,2729,5471,10949,21911,43853,87719,175447,350899};
    *int PrimesIndex=1;* **int PrimesIndex=0;**  **//changed.**


     HashTable *createHashTable(size)
    {
         HashTable *new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table)*size);

        if (new_table == NULL)
        {   return NULL;
        }

        int i=0;
        for(i; i<size; i++)
        {   new_table[i].length=0;
            new_table[i].head=NULL;
        }
        return new_table;
    }

    int hash ( HashTable *hashtable,char* number)
    {
        int hashval = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {   hashval = (hashval << 5)|(hashval >> 27);
            hashval += ( int)number[i];
        }

        return hashval % primes[PrimesIndex];
    }

         List *lookup ( HashTable *hashtable,int hashval,char number[10])
        {
         printf("NUMBER:%s\n",number);
          List *list=hashtable[hashval].head;
         for(list; list!=NULL; list=list->next){
           if (strcmp(number,list->number)==0)    
            return list;

         }
         return NULL;
        }


        int add ( HashTable* hashtable,char number[10],char* name,int time)
        {
             List *new_elem;
            int hashval=hash (hashtable,number);

            new_elem=hashtable[hashval].head;
            if(hashtable[hashval].length>0)
            {                   
                  if ((lookup (hashtable,hashval,number))!=NULL) {return 0;}    
            }

            if (!(new_elem=malloc(sizeof(struct  List)))){ return -1;}

            //insert values for the new elem
            new_elem->number=strdup(number);    
            new_elem->name=strdup(name);
            new_elem->time=time;

            hashtable[hashval].head=new_elem;
            new_elem->next=NULL;
            hashtable[hashval].length++;

            /* rehash existing entries if necessary */
            if(hashTableSize(hashtable)>= 2*primes[PrimesIndex])    
            {    
                 hashtable = expand(hashtable);
                 if (hashtable ==NULL){
                   return 0;
                 }

            }

            return 1;
        }

 HashTable* expand( HashTable* h )
{   printf("EXPAND \n");
     HashTable* new;
     List *temp;
    int n;
     List *node,*next;
    PrimesIndex++;
    int new_size= primes[PrimesIndex];      /* double the size,odd length */

    if (!(new=malloc((sizeof(  List*))*new_size))) return NULL;

    for(n=0; n< h->length; ++n) {
        for(node=h[n].head; node; node=next) {
            add (new, node->number, node->name,node->time);
            next=node->next;
            //free(node);
        }
    }
    free(h);
    return new;
}
```

and the main:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
    {
        char **token;
        FILE *delimitedFile;
        /*Here's an example of tokenizing lines from an actual file*/
        /*Open file for reading ("r"), and take a FILE pointer, 
          which you can use to fetch lines using fgets()*/

        my_hash_table = createHashTable(17);
        if(my_hash_table==NULL)
        {   return 1;
        }

        FILE * File2;
            if ( ( File2=fopen(" File.txt","r")) !=NULL ) 
            { // File.txt format:  [name number time]
                int li = 0;
                char *lin = (char *) malloc(MAX_LINE * sizeof(char));

                while(fgets(lin, MAX_LINE, File2) != NULL)
                {
                    token = my_linetok(lin, " ");
                    if(token != NULL)
                    {
          char* number ;
          char* name;
          int time;
          int i;
                        for(i = 0; token[i] != NULL; i++)
                        {
           name=strdup(token[0]);
           number=strdup(token[1]);
           time=atoi(token[2]);

           if (i==2)
           { int insertDone=0;
                 insertDone =add(my_hash_table,number,name,time);   

           } 
          }
          free(name); 
          free(number);
          free(token);

                    }
                    else 
             {
                        printf("Error reading line %s\n", lin);
                        exit(1);   
                    }
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("Error opening file \nEXIT!");
         exit(0);
            }

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: I imagine this isn't the cause of your segfault, but don't you want to be comparing against `list->number`, not `list->name`?

Comment: Also, the backtrace implies you're in a function called `lookup()`, called from a function called `add()`.  Where are these?

Comment: You free `name`, but don't free `number`. Does your function `add()` allocate memory to hold both `number` and `name`, or just for `number`?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth. OK that was from copy paste. Updated post. U can check add() function.

Comment: @DReJ Thanks for noticing that. I forgot it cause before number was taken as a long int. :/

Comment: @FILIaS: That still doesn't explain the `lookup()`/`lookup_on_Clients()` discrepancy!  Are you sure this is the code that corresponds to your backtrace?

Comment: Also, have you noticed that `list = 0xffffffff`?

Comment: @FILIaS: You still haven't posted the definition of `struct HashTable` or of `my_hash_table`.  -1.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth. Sorry for that.Just copy paste mistake. Yes i noticed that. :/ But i dont know why its like that :/ If u have any idea i would be grateful

Comment: @j_random_hacher.I just posted it.

Comment: Where is `PrimesIndex` defined?  I get the feeling it's a global variable -- when it should be a per-hashtable quantity, or a local variable, recomputed from the size of the hashtable.  Also we need to see `createClientsHashTable()` and `my_linetok()`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker. my_linetok is a different file.and i could be feel safe about it us it was given to me as a company file. Im gonna post now createHashTable. yes PrimesIndex is global as primes too.  EDIT: Posted.

Comment: What is `clientFile2`?  Is it `File2`?  Please post the exact code!

Comment: Why does `main()` contain a loop `for(i = 0; token[i] != NULL; i++)` that then processes specific items (rather than the ith token)?  You are currently calling `strdup()` multiple times inside this loop, and only `free()`ing the last version.  That won't cause a crash (unless you run out of memory) but it is a memory leak.

Comment: It processes specific items as in each line of the file there are: name number time, how can they be added to the structure without the loop? You are right for the free() but if i free them inside the loop, how can i then call add function with these?

Comment: @FILIaS: No, the `while` loop iterates once for each line in the file.  It's not necessary (and in fact is wasteful) to have the `for` loop I mentioned in my previous comment inside that `while` loop.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok thanks for that. Any ideas why list is marked as  list = 0xffffffff ?? :/

Comment: @FILIaS: No, but it shouldn't be too hard to track down why it becomes that, either by stepping in the debugger, or by adding printf statements.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth. Maybe you are right.But a "mature sight" would be better on these cases.

Comment: This is hilarious.  `expand()`, which you only posted in the most recent update, contains 2 separate bugs that will cause crashes, plus a 3rd bug that will cause a large memory leak.  And I've just noticed a bug in `add()` that ensures that no hash bucket ever contains more than 1 element.  (As well as another memory leak -- *for a change*.)

Comment: @ j_random_hacker. Im happy that my mistakes make you lauph a bit as you say. At least im working on it.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem here is that you create a hashtable with 17 buckets:

```
my_hash_table = createHashTable(17);
```

But C arrays are 0-based, and `PrimesIndex` starts out at 1, not 0, so inside `add()`, the call to `hash()`:

```
int hashval=hash (hashtable,number);
```

will return a number between 0 and 28, not a number between 0 and 16.  So at some point, an out-of-range value will be assigned to `hashval`, and one of the subsequent accesses indexed by `hashval`, e.g.

```
new_elem=hashtable[hashval].head;
```

will be reading uninitialised memory, leading ultimately to crazy pointer values like `0xffffffff` surfacing later on.

**Solution:** Change `int PrimesIndex = 1;` to `int PrimesIndex = 0;`.

But honestly, I think there could well be other issues that I'm missing.  There are:

- Issues with the `for` loop inside the `while` loop in `main()` that I've pointed out in comments;
- The dubious declaration for the `number` parameter to `lookup_on_Clients()`;
- The fact that sometimes the function is called `lookup()` and sometimes `lookup_on_Clients()` (as noticed by Oli);
- And I don't trust that `my_linetok()` (which you don't show source for) works properly -- at the very least, unless it uses a static buffer, it must be allocating an array of `char *` in order to hold the pointers to the individual tokens, which is never freed -- a memory leak.

Comment: That's right. Well the only reason that PrimesIndex was 1 is that from the beginning i create a hash table with 17 buckets (the first number on primes) so i thought it was useless to start it from 0. Anyway,i believe the same,it;s not this the serious problem.(EDIT: I meant PrimesIndex,for any case i changed it!)

Comment: @FILIaS: **YES** this is **the** problem.  What don't you understand about my explanation?

Comment: @j_random_hacker. For the first one: I already changed that thanks. Second note: dubious yes. But what can i do for better? Third note: Thats from copy paste dont pay attention to these. Fourth one: For what i see yes this code has leaks. But im not meant to change it, so...

Comment: @FILIaS: So you changed it to `int PrimesIndex = 0;` and you still get the same problem?

Comment: @j_random_hacker. Now i got what u mean with PrimesIndex i didnt notice that i use it on hash(). Thanks.

Comment: @j_random_hacker. Well,i changed it,now it doesnt crash from the beginning but yes i get segmentation again

Comment: @j_random_hacker Should i provide you the new messages on gdb?

Comment: @FILIaS: So there are other problems besides the one I identified -- I'm not surprised.  I'm sorry but you are infuriating.  I have just spent most of the last hour trying to help you, and for what?  You couldn't even be bothered *trying* the solution I have carefully worked out and explained to you.  Nor are you prepared to show your thanks with an upvote.  Don't bother showing me the latest gdb message -- I'm not interested in helping you any longer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I;m sorry for you thinking like this. I was going to upvote. But this is all? The upvoting? Im just trying to solve my problem.Ok. I didnt check it IMMEDIATELY. But all this is for that? Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for downvoting btw. Thanx for "infuriating" too. Its clearly from your first comment here...who;s infuriating.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a room for null terminator in `number`. You set size of `number` to be equal to 10 chars, but you have 10 digits in your number and no space for \0.

EDIT:

I looked your updated code. You created hashtable of initial size = 17, but your hasval = 27. But you don't have code to extend the size of hashtable properly.

```
new_elem=hashtable[hashval].head;
if(hashtable[hashval].length>0) // <-- when hashval is out of array 
                                // hashtable[hashval] can have any value of length and head (not NULL)
```

Comment: While you are sure that \0 in the original string was not replaced with other data it's ok. But in common it's unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: So,what should i do for better?

Comment: Try `strncmp(number,list->number,10)` just to make sure

Comment: @DReJ. Checked it. It's the same. None change to results. You can re-check my post if you mind as I posted some new functions.Thanks

Comment: @DReJ. That's right. So should i change my hash()??? :/ Or the initial size of the table?

Comment: @DReJ. For what i tracked down the problem is my expand(). Without calling this,everything is fine now. So the problem remains on that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually show the source for `add()` which presumably calls `lookup_on_Clients()`, and the backtrace mentions `lookup()` instead of `lookup_on_Clients()`, so I can't be sure, but here's my diagnosis:

- The backtrace says `list = 0xffffffff` -- that's definitely not a valid address, so it's probably the `list->name` access that is causing the SIGSEGV.
- I'm also bothered by the fact that the `number` parameter to `lookup_on_Clients()` is declared as `char number[10]` and yet gdb shows it contains a 10-digit number -- that suggests that the variable holding the argument for this is declared the same way, meaning that there's no room for a terminating 0 byte.  And the fact that you're calling `strcmp()` on it means that you are treating `number` as nul-terminated string, so the variable holding the argument that gets passed to `lookup_on_Clients()` as `number` (possibly a local variable declared in `add()`?) should be declared as an array with size at least 11 to avoid crashes.  You're safe if `add()` just passes its own `number` argument straight through, since that is dynamically allocated to be large enough via `strdup()` in `main()`, but I would nevertheless change the declaration on `lookup_on_Clients()`.

Comment: I posted add() function.You can check.